# Optimizing data inserts for HibernateTemplate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, optimization, dao

I have to optimize the database (especially insert) performance of a certain legacy tool. The tool has been written in Java and for the data access layer *Spring + HibernateTemplate* was the technology of choice.

The actual problem is doing some bulk inserts. We have to insert more than **50K** data by calling *HibernateTemplate.save()* for each. This is apparently a very inefficient way but because of the lack of time, we cannot change the implementation for now.

What would be the optimization patterns other than changing the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things I can think of, if you want to optimize code without modifying the code are :

- try larger values for [hibernate.jdbc.batch_size](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-jdbc-properties)
- use a faster disk and machine for your database

If you're ready to slightly change the code, then follow [the advices of the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-inserts), and regularly flush and clear the session while inserting your data. Or use a stateless session.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not really experienced with hibernate and caching things but i was wondering if some second-level cache solutions would help here?

Comment: The second-level cache would make things worse. A cache is useful when getting things out of the database, to avoid getting to the database and get it directly from the cache. But every insert would have to write to the cache in addition to writing to the database.